# Embedding facebook feed into html

Tags: html, css, xhtml, feed

I would like to integrate a facebook feed into a html page.
I have researched alot and have found a couple of ways to do this, but none of them seem to work...

The method I think would be most effective, is using iFrames. But whenever I load one into my page, I get an error.
The error states that he couldn't find the file or directory. The error is stated in a grey rectangle with a frowning smiley.

Do note, i'm still creating this website, so all of the content is offline and is accessed through my computer.

Cheers!

here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Sample</title>
        <link href="_resources/styles/sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    </head>
    <body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207087449372135";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-width="200" data-height="500" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple no programming needed check here -- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

You need to put this code just after the opening body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207087449372135";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And paste this below code wherever you want to display the Feed.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

**[CHECK OUT THE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mumsQ/)**

Comment: I just edited my question so it includes my html code. Could you have a look what I'm doing wrong? I'm still not getting any result...

Comment: I think you are running this code in local machine not online. Thats why its not working.. replace `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207087449372135` with `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207087449372135` if you want to see the working example.